# Reverse the words of a string using Java

Tags: java, strings

I wrote this program which reverses the words in a given string. Please review and give your inputs.

```
private static void reverseWords(String value) {
    // reverse the whole string
    value = reverseInOofN2Time(value);

    // now split (on space) the string into an string array
    String[] strArr = value.split(" ");

    // make it empty
    value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        // reverse each strArr element and append it to the value
        value += reverseInOofN2Time(strArr[i]) + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(value);
}

public static String reverseInOofN2Time(String h) {
    char[] charArr = h.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length / 2; i++) {
        char temp = charArr[i];
        int targetPos = (charArr.length - 1) - i;
        charArr[i] = charArr[targetPos];
        charArr[targetPos] = temp; 

    }
    return new String(charArr);
}
```

Comment: Why is it called `reverseInOofN2Time` when the time is \$O(n)\$ and not \$O(n^2)\$?  And in fact, why do you even reverse the string only to reverse it back later?

Comment: Where is the swap method? Where is this c variable?

This looks like a snippet and/or broken.

Comment: I am sorry I missed to add the swap method, actually the intention was to get my logic in "reverseWords" method gets reviewed. I had renamed the variables by editing my post in stackoverflow, and I missed to replace "c" with "charArr".

Comment: I don't see `reverseInOn2Time()` anywhere in the code, either.

Comment: @Hosch250 my bad, my post going horrible for me.. lesson learnt is never edit code after post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic gets a little confusing to when you get to the `for` loop.

To me, when you were reversing the string at the very beginning and then splitting it up into words, I figured you were going to append the words in reverse order in to a blank string.

Then, for some reason, you start reversing all the words in `strArr`.

It makes more sense with the beginning of your logic to continue as I thought it was going to continue.

Here is little bit more into my idea:

---

```
"abc def"
```

---

First, reverse the string:

```
"fed cba"
```

---

Split the string up by spaces:

```
["fed", "cba"]
```

---

Right the elements of the array in reverse order to a blank string, putting a space between each word:

```
"cba def"
```

---

Here is my solution in Java:

```
value = reverseInOn2Time(value);
String[] words = value.split(" ");
StringBuilder blank = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = words.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    blank.append(words[i] + " ");
}

return blank.toString();
```

*I used a `StringBuiler` to increase efficiency because `StringBuilder`s are mutable, unlike `String`s.*

---

Another solution you could have is to first split up the string into words, then reverse them, and then stick them all into a blank.

Here is a little bit more into that option:

---

```
"abc def"
```

---

First, split up the string by space:

```
["abc", "def"]
```

---

Reverse each element of the array:

```
["cba", "def"]
```

---

Write the elements of the array to a blank string:

```
"cba def"
```

---

Here is that solution in Java:

```
String[] words = value.split(" ")
StringBuilder blank = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = reverseInOn2Time(words[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    blank.append(words[i] + " ");
}

return blank.toString();
```

---

I personally would choose the first solution.

*These snippets assume that `reverseInOn2Time` reverses a string, as stated by the comments near the function call.*

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable, for the value you later "empty", you should be using a `StringBuilder` for its mutability, which I doubly recommend since it comes packed with a [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) method.

### Reversing a string

```
public static String reverse(String str) {  
        return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    }
```

So if you wanted to individually reverse the words, simply split on the spaces, reverse using StringBuilder, and append to a second result StringBuilder.

### Reversing words, individually.

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : str.split("\\s+")) {
            result.append(' ').append(reverse(s));
        }

        return result.substring(1);
    }
```